# Unable to interchange attributes of a button on checkbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, materialize

I am using jquery to enable/disable buttons on select/un-select of a checkbox. There are two set of buttons one is "Delete" which delete only one record, and "Delete Multiple" which deletes all those records which are selected.

The problem is when I check one or more checkboxes the "Delete" button disables(only style) but is still functional. When I uncheck the checkboxes the "Delete Multiple" button disbales(again only style) and "Delete" button doesn't enables back. I am using Materialize.

The code is as follows :

HTML Code:

```
@foreach($engines as $engine)
    <td>
      <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn red modal-trigger searchDelete" href="#searchDelete" data-id="{{$engine->id}}" data-name="{{$engine->name}}">Delete</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="switch">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="ids" class="id-search" value="{{$engine->id}}">
                    <span class="lever"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
@endforeach
```

Jquery Code:

```
$('.id-search').on('change',function () {
var ids = [];
$('input:checkbox[name=ids]:checked').each(function () {
    ids.push($(this).val());
});
var length = ids.length;
if (length > 0) {
    $('#deleteMultipleSearch').attr('class','btn waves-effect waves-light red modal-trigger');
    $('.searchDelete').attr('class', 'btn disabled');
    $('.searchDelete').removeAttr('class', 'modal-trigger searchDelete');
    console.log("Id clicked");
}
else {
    $('#deleteMultipleSearch').attr('class', 'btn disabled');
    $('.searchDelete').removeAttr('class', 'btn disabled');
    $('.searchDelete').attr('class', 'btn red');
}
});
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: it just enable the multiple delete button still the single delete works and but when i unchecked all, the multiple delete works and the properties of single buttons does not reverts back.

Comment: could you post the rendered html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you should use Jquery **addClass** and removeClass API's instead of **attr** and **removeAttr** for manipulating the classes...
Try this javascript code

```
$('.id-search').on('change',function () {
    var ids = [];
    $('input:checkbox[name=ids]:checked').each(function () {
        ids.push($(this).val());
    });
    var length = ids.length;
    if (length > 0) {
        $('#deleteMultipleSearch').addClass('btn waves-effect waves-light red modal-trigger');
        $('.searchDelete').addClass('btn disabled');
        $('.searchDelete').removeClass('modal-trigger searchDelete');
        console.log("Id clicked");
    }
    else {
        $('#deleteMultipleSearch').addClass('btn disabled');
        $('.searchDelete').removeClass('btn disabled');
        $('.searchDelete').addClass('btn red');
    }
});
```

Good luck